# Unable to deploy a Next.js monorepo using workspaces to Vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel

I've been having Vercel deployment issues when trying to convert my existing Nextjs app to be a monorepo using  either `npm` or `yarn` workspaces. After changing to a monorepo, my builds are failing due to a  package `Not found` issue.

You can see the full repository [on GitHub in the `monorepo-testing` branch](https://github.com/saadq/proposals.es/tree/monorepo-testing).

I essentially have two npm packages:

- `proposals.es`: This package is the actual Next.js app (located in the `./website` folder)
- `@common/components`: This package contains simple React components (located in the `./common/components` folder)

The folder structure for this currently looks like this:

```
.
├── next-env.d.ts
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── common
│   └── components 
│       ├── index.ts
│       └── package.json 
└── website 
    ├── next.config.js
    ├── package.json
    ├── src
    └── tsconfig.json
```

To get the app to install correctly and run successfully locally, I run `npm install --workspaces` from the root level and then run `npm run dev` from within `website` to start the server.

---

I have done the following steps to try to get this new monorepo structure to work:

- I added `workspaces` to [my root level `package.json`](https://github.com/saadq/proposals.es/blob/monorepo-testing/package.json#L4-L7):
- I added `next-transpile-modules` to my [Next config file](https://github.com/saadq/proposals.es/blob/monorepo-testing/website/next.config.js#L3)
- I added `@common/components` to [my website's `package.json`](https://github.com/saadq/proposals.es/blob/monorepo-testing/website/package.json#L20)
- I [imported my common component in a page](https://github.com/saadq/proposals.es/blob/monorepo-testing/website/src/pages/wasm/index.tsx#L1) and rendered it (this works fine when running the dev server)

---

I end up getting this error when trying to do an automatic deployment to Vercel after a `git push`:

```
Installing dependencies...
Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7...
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@common%2fcomponents - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@common/components@*' is not in this registry.
```

My Vercel settings are here:

[image]

All settings are default, except the root directory is set to `website`. I was thinking that the issue might be that it is not using `npm install --workspaces` to do the installation, however I have tried changing the install script in my Vercel project to `npm install --workspaces` as well as `cd ../../ && npm install --workspaces` but both would error out.

I feel like I'm probably doing something fundamentally wrong, so if anyone has any tips or suggestions on how to tackle this issue it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! I'm having the same problem. But I'm using an experimental `externalDir` flag to compile modules instead of `next-transpile-modules`.

Comment: And you're running into the same issue when using `externalDir` instead? I haven't had a chance to revisit this issue though, I just ended up getting it resolved by using `yarn` workspaces instead of `npm` workspaces

Comment: Looks like it doesn't reach that moment when `externalDir` comes into play. Tried dozens of ways to customize install and build commands but without any success. I'm afraid I have to switch to Yarn as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue seems to be with using `npm` workspaces with Next.js... When I switched over to a minimal POC using `yarn` workspaces it seems to be working. Going to try to convert everything to using `yarn` now and see if it's all better afterwards, I'll update here once I do so.

---

Edit: Was able to successfully deploy the two apps now and I was able to import my common package from them.

Repo: https://github.com/saadq/proposals.es

Comment: I also had to switch to Yarn to make it work. And I can confirm: with Yarn workspaces everything works with default deployment settings in Vercel (just choose the right directory of the project). Another important thing for me was choosing `nodeLinker: node-modules`.

Comment: Hmm interesting, I didn't have to set `nodeLinker` explicitly. I wonder if it's a case-by-case basis

Comment: Can confirm the Turborepo [Basic starter example](https://github.com/vercel/turborepo/tree/main/examples/basic) deploys to Vercel when using Yarn, but fails when using npm workspaces: `No Next.js version could be detected in your project.`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Saad's answer, we had to manually set the install step to `yarn install`. It appears it was using `npm install` by default, which was not working.

[image]

Also, make sure that you are using the `next-transpile-modules` library in your `next.config.js` file and specifying any shared package you want to use from your monorepo:

```js
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(['@your/shared-package']); // pass the modules you would like to see transpiled

const nextConfig = withTM({
  experimental: {
    externalDir: true, // This allows importing TS/TSX from outside of the current Next.js project root directory. See: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/22867
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on our experience, this looks like an issue with Vercel not yet supporting Node v15+ (npm workspaces were introduced in npm v7).

Running our monorepo's Next.js project locally on Node v15 or v16 works as expected, but deploying to Vercel (currently only support Node v12.x and v14.x ([docs](https://vercel.com/docs/runtimes#official-runtimes/node-js/node-js-version)) we start to see lockfile version warnings and "package not found" errors. Hopefully we'll see an upgrade here soon ([discussion](https://github.com/vercel/community/discussions/37)) and can continue to use `npm`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [vdutz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71973177/6541042) for future reference:

NextJS has incorporated the transpiling module (see [Next config transpilePackages](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/transpilePackages)).

The new config would result like this:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  transpilePackages: ['insert package name here'],
}
 
module.exports = nextConfig
```

This works perfectly with PNPM Workspaces as well!